# Save image to disk directly from SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, sql-server-2008, save

I will preface this question with the fact that I don't know if this is possible and that I don't know a ton about sql or file structures.

I have a sql server database with a column of type image. I want to save one of these images to disk without having to write a program (if possible). So in an ideal world I would run a query in Sql Server Management Studio. RMB on a result cell and save as image to disk.

This of course doesn't work, but is what I am after possible? I did search SO and Google, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL Server are you using?  SQL 2008 supports FILESTREAM where you can save BLOB data directly to an NTFS volume.  There is a good blog article about it here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rdoherty/archive/2007/10/12/getting-traction-with-sql-server-2008-filestream.aspx

Comment: Thank you. The article was a bit over my head though. May I have an Easy button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @ObjectToken int
declare @signature varbinary(8000)  --  Load @signature with the value of your image, I have not tested varbinary(max) with sp_oacreate
declare @fullname varchar(500)  --  Load @fullname with folder and filename to export to

exec sp_oacreate 'ADODB.Stream', @objecttoken output
exec sp_oasetproperty @objecttoken, 'type', 1
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'open'
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'write', null, @signature
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'savetofile', null, @FullName, 2
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'close'
exec sp_oadestroy @objecttoken
```

Comment: This looked promising, but apparently I do not have Execute permission on the db I have to use. This looks intriguing though and I think I will try and test it on another, local db.